# Django-Compressor throws UncompressableFileError on bower installed asset

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-compressor

When I run my unit tests I am getting `UncompressableFileError` for files installed through Bower. This happens because I don't run `bower install` in my unit tests and I don't want to have to run `bower install` for my unit tests.

Is there a way to disable django-compressor, or to mock the files so that this error doesn't happen?

I have `COMPRESS_ENABLED` set to `False` but no luck there, it still looks for the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you also set `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = ()` in your test-specific settings, that should fix your problem.